# Why doesn't my view display headers?

Tags: c++, qt

This is a class copied from the Qt tutorials:

```
class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Window();

    void setSourceModel();

private slots:
    void filterRegExpChanged();
    void filterColumnChanged();
    void sortChanged();
    void addMail();

private:
    QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;
    QStandardItemModel *model;

    QGroupBox *sourceGroupBox;
    QGroupBox *proxyGroupBox;

    QTreeView *sourceView;
    QTreeView *proxyView;
    QCheckBox *filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox;
    QCheckBox *sortCaseSensitivityCheckBox;
    QLabel *filterPatternLabel;
    QLabel *filterSyntaxLabel;
    QLabel *filterColumnLabel;
    QLineEdit *filterPatternLineEdit;
    QComboBox *filterSyntaxComboBox;
    QComboBox *filterColumnComboBox;
    QPushButton* button;
};
```

This is a def of a ctor:

```
Window::Window()
{
    model = new QStandardItemModel(this);  
//HEADERS ARE NOT DISPLAYED EVEN THOUGH I'M SETTING THEM HERE
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Subject"));
    model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Sender"));
    model->setHeaderData(2, Qt::Horizontal, QObject::tr("Date"));

    proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
    proxyModel->setDynamicSortFilter(true);

    sourceView = new QTreeView;
    sourceView->setRootIsDecorated(false);
    sourceView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);

    proxyView = new QTreeView;
    proxyView->setRootIsDecorated(false);
    proxyView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    proxyView->setModel(proxyModel);
    proxyView->setSortingEnabled(true);

connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(addMail()));//THIS SEEMS NOT TO MAKE ANY DIFFERENCE - NOTHING IS ADDED
};  

void Window::addMail()
{
    model->insertRow(0);
    model->setData(model->index(0, 0), "subject");
    model->setData(model->index(0, 1), "sender");
    model->setData(model->index(0, 2), "date");
}  
void Window::setSourceModel()
{
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
    sourceView->setModel(model);
}  
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Window window;
    window.setSourceModel();
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Neither headers nor data added via addMail are displayed. Why?

Answer (score 6):

QAbstractItemModel::setHeaderData is meant to handle user edits of the header, not setting them programmatically. The model then must implement setHeaderData to handle those edit requests. QStandardItemModel apparently doesn't create header items if they weren't set initially, so nothing happens.

As you're using QStandardItemModel, you should use [setHorizontalHeaderItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setHorizontalHeaderItem) or [setHorizontalHeaderLabels](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setHorizontalHeaderLabels) (Vertical variants are also available) to set up the header.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the documentation, you will take notice, that setHeaderData takes four parameters, with the last one being the role.
The role defaults to Qt::EditRole, but you probably want Qt::DisplayRole.